# How to populate this PHP array?

Tags: php, arrays

I have a outsource data from :

http://example.com/data/news.json

Here is the example result after decoding :

```
Array
(
    [popular] => Array
        (
            [last_week] => Array
                (
                    [0] => Array
                        (
                           [title] => Business 1
                            [category] => blog/business/local
                        )
                    [1] => Array
                        (
                        [title] => Health 1
                        [category] => blog/health/skincare
                    )
                [2] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Business 2
                        [category] => blog/business/local
                    )
                [3] => Array
                    (
                        [title] => Health 2
                        [category] => blog/health/skincare
                    )
            )
    )

)
```

I'm use following method to display it :

```
$url = 'http://example.com/data/news.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
if(!empty($json)) {
$json_data = json_decode($json, true);
$popular_last_week = $json_data['popular']['last_week'];
$count = count($popular_last_week);
$result .= $count.' last week popular article' . "\n";
for ($i = 0;  $i <$count; $i++) {
$result .= 'Title : '.$popular_last_week[$i]['title'] . "\n";
$result .= 'Category : '.$popular_last_week[$i]['category'] . "\n\n";
}
echo $result;
}
```

and the output data is :

*4 last week popular articles*

*Title : Business 1*
Category : blog/business/local

*Title : Health 1*
*Category : blog/health/skincare*

*Title : Business 2*
*Category : blog/business/local*

*Title : Health 2*
*Category : blog/health/skincare*

The question is how to display the output to be following :

*2 last week popular Business articles*

*Title : Business 1*
*Category : Busines*

*Title : Business 2*
*Category : Business*

*2 last week popular Health articles*

*Title : Health 1*
*Category : Health*

*Title : Health 2*
*Category : Health*

help would be greatly appreciated! thank you.

Comment: Not sure if I understand correctly ... Simply iterate through the array, check if `title` contains `Business` and display it?

Comment: Hi, Thanks for your answer I'm new with PHP and it would be great if you give an example. :-D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you mean that you only want to show 2 items? You need to use a `for` loop.

```
for ($i = 0;  $i < 2; $i++) {
    # display for $i
}
```

Update:

Ah, I think I understand. You should use a `foreach` loop and loop through twice:

```
$categoryItems = array();
foreach ($popular_last_week as $item) {
    $categoryItems[$item['category']][] = $item['title'];
}
foreach ($categoryItems as $category => $items) {
    $result .= count($items) . ' popular in category ' . $category;
    foreach ($items as $item){
        $result .= 'Title: ' . $item['title'] . "\n";
    }
}
echo $result;
```

Comment: Hi, Yes I'm also put that code but I don't know maybe eaten by editor

Comment: Please see my updates, sorry it's hard to format when typing on my phone

Comment: You know, Pateman copied my answer. You should have accepted mine.

Answer (score 3):

```
$url = 'http://example.com/data/news.json';
$json = file_get_contents($url);
if(!empty($json)) {
    $json_data = json_decode($json, true);
    $popular_last_week = $json_data['popular']['last_week'];

    //  This loop will group all entries by category.
    $categories = array();
    foreach ($popular_last_week as $item) {
        $categories[$item['category']][] = $item['title'];
    }

    //  This loop will echo the titles grouped by categories.
    foreach ($categories as $category => $titles) {
        $result = count($titles) . ' popular in "' . $category . '"' . "\n";
        foreach ($titles as $title) {
            $result .= 'Title: ' . $title . "\n";
        }
        echo $result;
    }
}
```

Comment: the category is taken to be **only** business

Comment: The problem is the title is not always contains "Business".

Comment: Let assumsing I've 4 articles (any words) with 2 categories "blog/business/local" and "blog/health/skincare" and I want to display them populated by category.

Comment: Wow that exactly what I want, you're rock buddy!! thanks a lot!